# Machine learning random forest classifier

Tags: python, pandas

```
data=pd.DataFrame({'gender':['m','f','m'],'icds':[['i10'],['i20','i30'],['i40']],'med':[[1,2,4,5],[3,4,6],[5,6,7]]})
```

Which machine learning algorithm shall I use for this type of data? I think of the inconsistent length of arrays in the `med` column. Whenever I try to pass it in the random forest classifier, `med` column is basically the labels.

Comment: and one more thing it is a multi label problem

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you are right, the algorithm you should use is RF or logistic also should be good. The issue is with the inconsistent length of data in 'med' column. If its not necessary you can use the following functions to average/sum out the numerical data in med columns arrays:

```
def sum_out(x):
return np.nansum(x)
```

def avg_out(x):
    return np.nanmean(x)

data=pd.DataFrame({'gender':['m','f','m'],'icds':[['i10'],['i20','i30'],['i40']],'med':[[1,2,4,5],[3,4,6],[5,6,7]]})

data['med_sum']= data['med'].map(sum_out)
data['med_avg']= data['med'].map(avg_out)

Comment: but what if the data in the meds column are labels ,like name of medicines, i can not sum them for example the med column is  in the form ['brufen','panadol'],['xanex']. Now here you can see that the length of list is not consistent and Random Forest is not accepting it, can you help me what to do in this case ?

Comment: @SIDDIQI For RF you could split the label list into multiple features: one bool for each label. This could work if you don't have too many different labels.

Comment: so basically doing this by using Multilabelbinarizer and then passing it as y-labels right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually add those meds as features, something like this:

```
data=pd.DataFrame({'gender':['m','f','m'],'icds':[['i10'],['i20','i30'],['i40']],'med':[['xanex','isotopin'],['cz3','hicet','t-montair'],['t-montair','xanex']]}) 


all_med= list(np.unique(flatten(list(data['med'].values))))

for meds in all_med:
    med_list=[]
    for i in xrange(len(data)):
        d= data['med'][i]
        if meds in d:
            med_list.append(1)
        else:
            med_list.append(0)
    data[meds]=med_list
```

Output:

```
  gender        icds                      med  cz3  hicet  isotopin  \
0      m       [i10]        [xanex, isotopin]    0      0         1
1      f  [i20, i30]  [cz3, hicet, t-montair]    1      1         0
2      m       [i40]       [t-montair, xanex]    0      0         0

   t-montair  xanex
0          0      1
1          1      0
2          1      1
```

Comment: what you are doing is that you are actually doing one-hot encoding right ?

Comment: okay , but is there any other algorithm that directly takes such kind of data or handles it ? like without encoding it ?

Comment: I don't think so, features you got to build yourself based on the data. Also the features you build based on the data would give you a much better prediction and accuracy.